# Get user email from facebook connect with SDK java script in v2.8

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can not retrieve the facebook e-mail address of a person who connects with the facebook login button. I use JDK java script in 2.8 version

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" auto_logout_link="true"></fb:login-button>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<appId>',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.8'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_FR/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            //console.log('Check login state');
            //console.log(response);
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Connected');
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            console.log('Please log into this app');
        } else {
            console.log('Please log into Facebook.');
        }
    }

    function testAPI() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api(
                    '/me',
                    {fields: 'id,email,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,timezone,updated_time,verified'},
                    function (response) {
                        console.log('response');
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },{scope:'email'});        
    }

    function testLogout() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have all the information except the email. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Did the user actually grant the email permission? And is the email address verified? It won’t be returned if it isn’t.

Comment: Yes the email is verified in my object response (verified:true) and I accepted all the permissions during the connection.

Comment: That fields means whether the profile itself is verified, it has nothing to do with the email.

Comment: The profile and the email is different ? How to check if the email is verified ?

Comment: Yes, a verified profile means verified by text message or via credit card. You can not explicitly check if the email is verified, there is no extra field for that. Try the request in Graph API Explorer, if it returns the email there, it is an issue with your code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to debug the Facebook token that you are using via the token debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken and verify that the email field is present.

Comment: I tested with another account and it works. I can successfully retrieve the e-mail address. But it still does not work with my facebook account. I have to make a special setting in the facebook account configuration ? I thank you very much for making me discover the graph API Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
FB.api(
                '/me',
                {fields: 'id,email,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,timezone,updated_time,verified'},
                function (response) {
                    console.log('response');
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
```

To:

```
FB.api(
                '/me?fields=id,email,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,timezone,updated_time,verified',
                function (response) {
                    console.log('response');
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
```